# What class instance should be used for request of authenticate()?

Tags: python, django, ldap, openldap

I have backend which uses the `Ldap`

```
class MyLDAPBackend(LDAPBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print("Try ldap auth")
        print(type(request)) # <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>
        user = LDAPBackend.authenticate(request, username, password,kwargs)
```

This shows the error like this,

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'settings'
```

So, I checked the source code in `[django-auth-ldap][1]` library.

```
class LDAPBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            return None

        if password or self.settings.PERMIT_EMPTY_PASSWORD:
            ldap_user = _LDAPUser(self, username=username.strip(), request=request)
            user = self.authenticate_ldap_user(ldap_user, password)
        else:
            logger.debug("Rejecting empty password for %s", username)
            user = None

        return user
```

It expect the instance which has access to `settings.py`, however framework pass the `<class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>` to authenticate.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `self.settings.PERMIT_EMPTY_PASSWORD`?

Comment: `user = LDAPBackend.authenticate(request, username, password,kwargs)` your passing `request` in where it's expecting `self` instead do `user = super().authenticate(request, username, password,kwargs)`